# Properly create a double Window behavior

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I'd like to create a proper "double Window behavior". If you don't see what I mean, here's a screenshot :

[image]

For now, I've this code :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    Window sideWindow;

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        sideWindow = new SideWindow() { Owner = this };
        AdjustSideWindow();
        sideWindow.Show();
    }

    private void AdjustSideWindow(bool heightChanged = false) {
        if (!(sideWindow == null)) {
            if (heightChanged) sideWindow.Height = this.Height;
            sideWindow.Left = this.Left + this.Width;
            sideWindow.Top = this.Top;
        }
    }

    private void Window_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        AdjustSideWindow();
    }

    private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) {
        AdjustSideWindow(e.HeightChanged);
    }
}
```

But I'm not satisfied : there's some flickering when moving/resizing quickly the `MainWindow` because the `LocationChanged` and `SizeChanged` are not raised as fast as the mouse is moving. The result is that the `SideWindow` is not moving exactly the same way as the `MainWindow`.

I was wondering if there was a lower level way to do it. For example with a bit of P/Invoke or something like that...

...or any way to attach/bind/link the `Height` property of the two windows...

...otherwise, I could do it with a Timer with an Interval property of 1 millisecond, but it looks too much like hack for me.

Comment: As asked, your question is too broad. That said, it seems to me that what you ought to be doing is not two windows, but a single window with a two-column `Grid`, and a [`GridSplitter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter(v=vs.110).aspx) to control the two panels. You can see an example of how that would work here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36342084

Comment: No I want it to have 2 windows, just as TeamViewer 11.

Comment: +1 since I actually think this is a usueful question and don't think it's too broad. I'm quite interested for a solution to this... somehow tapping into the layouting system and synching up two not directly connected visuals.

Comment: @MarkusHütter Thank you :) I'm here to get ideas, it's normal that it may be a bit too broad...

Comment: So here's the thing. Another user has already discovered that a `Window` isn't just a regular control, it's a wrapper around the **WinAPI**, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137758/wpf-binding-window-height-to-viewmodel-property). This means that you **cannot** do traditional two-way binding on the `Width` and `Height`, or even one-way binding for that matter.

Comment: I'll see this, thanks :)